# Arc is drawing over rect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

First, I draw a circle using arc and fill it. (button 1)

Then, I draw a rect *over* it and another arc and fill it red. (button 2)

However, after the second function, the first arc stays there and turns red, all of a sudden. Help?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
function function1() {
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.arc(100, 200, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}
function function2() {
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.arc(300, 200, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
<button onClick="function1()">Button 1</button>
<button onClick="function2()">Button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

OH. WOW. I just had the same exact error as a question I posted literally like over a year ago, where I forgot to put `context.beginPath();`. Stupid me.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
function function1() {
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(100, 200, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}
function function2() {
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(300, 200, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
<button onClick="function1()">Button 1</button>
<button onClick="function2()">Button 2</button>
```